# Permisos Android con Google Play Permissions policy

Tags: android, permisos, sms

quiero esta vez vengo a comentarles y pedir su colaboración en Android,  desde el año pasado 2018, me han llegado mensajes de google acerca de una aplicación que tengo en la playstore que uso para enviar SMS a un dispositivo GPS.

Al parecer Google cambio las politicas para usar estos permisos:

```
READ_SMS, WRITE_SMS, RECEIVE_SMS, SEND_SMS
```

**Utilizar los grupos de permisos de SMS o registro de llamadas**
Google Play restringe el uso de [permisos sensibles o de alto riesgo](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303), como los grupos de permisos de [SMS](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303) o registro de llamadas.

El mensaje que llego ya 2 veces es el siguiente: [Mensaje gmail](https://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/vib/AEM7UVREsGmjd27kXglOGNeYNP7klEnFdw3zpdK6EbCA99yLFmSvQ0hiI83pcywJmJNmre1XmcZ3FgPcaSQ3Oop5Ar6fPxIoWoeJTPDjxb83wF9wK7p6H86XmC12v5M583zIP32isl8nXMdww_YP8eowkTy-ezPTQB6EhzmVabzF7fH2OyYlkBsK9UxEyBT2PQthbZtAnvJiMXRvm_9-qIhdKmJty3h5yEzJeiJYml-vTdWbkZs)

La cosa es que he enviado el formulario de apelación explicando que mi App depende de enviar y recibir SMS, y me rechazan indicando que estos permisos están reservados solo a desarrolladores específicos.

**EL PUNTO ES:**
Necesito ayuda haber si desde la programación puedo solicitar estos permisos dinamicamente, o como hacer para que mi App pueda enviar y leer SMS, como antes, 
 y que sea compatible con las versiones Android 5.0+

Al parecer Google eliminara este año a todas las App de la Playstore que envíen SMS y no estén en su lista de App permitidas para enviar SMS.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda en el tema de envió SMS y lectura en Android, compatible con las nuevas políticas de google.

Answer (score 4):

Recuerda que a partir de Android 6.0 (nivel de API 23), los usuarios conceden permisos  ([permisos riesgosos](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions#normal-dangerous)) a las apps mientras se ejecutan, no cuando instalan la app.

En el caso de los permisos relacionados a los [mensajes SMS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission_group#SMS) :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos están considerados como [permisos riesgosos](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions#normal-dangerous)

> Los [permisos riesgosos](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions#normal-dangerous) pueden permitir que la app acceda a información
>   confidencial del usuario. Si tu app tiene un permiso normal en su
>   manifiesto, el sistema concede el permiso automáticamente. Si tienes
>   un permiso peligroso, el usuario debe autorizar explícitamente a tu
>   app.

por lo tanto [deben ser requeridos de manera manual en tiempo de ejecución](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Este es un ejemplo, puedes pedir los permisos dentro del método `onCreate()` de tu Activity principal:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    ...

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS,Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS,Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
            255);

     ...
     ...
    }
```

y agregar el método `onRequestPermissionsResult()` :

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 255: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permiso denegado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

de esta forma al iniciar la aplicación serán requeridos los permisos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: OK, gracias voy a probar este método hoy mismo porque hasta mañana 9 de Enero del 2019 dio Google plazo para quitar estos permisos del Manifiesto, mañana habrá limpieza en la playstore

Comment: @YoGo ¿Te funcionó?

Comment: Muchas gracias, supongo que funciona,pero todavía no lo he probado, pues mi móvil tiene Android 5.0,  el problema inicial todavía no lo soluciono van 4 veces que lleno el formulario de google para pedir permiso de enviar SMS y nada, lo rechazan.

Comment: @Elenasys Sabes como solicitar permisos de envió de SMS considerado riesgoso en Android 5.0 o inferior, si solicito este permiso en el manifiesto al subirlo a la play store me rechaza la actualización.

Comment: @E_Blue Sabes como solicitar permisos de envió de SMS considerado riesgoso en Android 5.0 o inferior, si solicito este permiso en el manifiesto al subirlo a la play store me rechaza la actualización

Comment: Para permisos SMS  en Android 5.0 o inferior, únicamente debes definirlo en tu AndroidManifest.xml, no necesitas realizar la petición manual. Tienes el mensaje que te envió Google?@YoGo

Comment: @YoGo No, yo estoy en la misma, Google arruino mi aplicación, cuya función básica es enviar mensajes automatizados que el usuario configura. Google actualizo su lista de requisitos y entre ellos prohíbe enviar y recibir SMSs a aplicaciones que no sean la que el usuario define por defecto; por lo tanto solo UNA aplicación a la vez puede enviar y recibir SMS, no importa para que versión hagas la App.

Comment: @E_Blue OK, voy a estar muy al pendiente del tema por si alguien encuentra una solución, debe haber algo por hay que no he visto aun. Agradezco compartan cualquier avance del tema.

Answer (score 0):

Al subir el apk al Play Store, se muestran errores de seguridad debido a que se esta usando servicio sms o algunos servicios que son restringidos para aplicaciones nativas, para evitar dichos mensajes, se debe eliminar del manifiesto    y en su reemplazo se debe escribir código como el adjunto en el activity donde se requiera su uso:

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ListaCuentas.this,
                                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                                        MY_PERMISSIONS_SEND_SMS);
                            }
```