# SMS Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sms, mensajes

tengo este código para enviar mensajes de texto pero no esta funcionando, ¿Alguna idea de dónde puede estar el "error"? 
Me refiero a que no me llega el mensaje.

**Código:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText us, con;
    Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED&& ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                MainActivity.this,Manifest
                        .permission.SEND_SMS)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]
                    { Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,},1000);
        }else{}
        us=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        con=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                enviarMensaje("","prueba");
            }
        });
    }

    private void enviarMensaje (String numero, String mensaje){
        try {
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(numero,null,mensaje,null,null);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Revisaste que se muestra en el LogCat? en el número a marcar se agrega el código de área?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para enviar SMS requieres básicamente 3 cosas,

- [Definir en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` y requerir manualmente el permiso SEND_SMS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/227304/permisos-android-con-google-play-permissions-policy)
- Tu dispositivo debe tener soporte telefónico ( `GSM` o `CDMA` ).
- El teléfono a enviar el mensaje debe escribirse con el código de área.

Tu ejemplo debe funcionar sin problema, si se cumplen los puntos indicados, recuerda usar el import indicado:

```
import android.telephony.SmsManager;

private void enviarMensaje (String numero, String mensaje){
    try {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(numero,null,mensaje,null,null);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

revisa este ejemplo:

[Permisos para enviar Mensajes de Texto (enviar SMS)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8480/android-6-0-permisos-para-enviar-mensajes-de-texto-enviar-sms)