# Enviar Mensajes a Diferentes Personas desde Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un LisView con diferentes personas, y quisiera que dependiendo de la persona que se seleccione mande un mensaje a esa persona. ¿Es posible?

```
enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            enviarMensaje("333333333","sms de prueba");
        }
    });

private void enviarMensaje(String numero, String mensaje) { 
    try { 
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault(); 
        sms.sendTextMessage(numero, null, mensaje, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mensaje enviado", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }catch (Exception e){ 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ocurrio un error inesperado, mensaje no enviado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
}
```

Es decir, en vez de poner un solo numero, un array con los numeros cargados para poder pasarselos y que de ahi seleccione los numeros.

Comment: Si es posible, ¿Que realiza tu método : enviarMensaje() ?,  agrega el código de este método

Comment: private void enviarMensaje(String numero, String mensaje) {
            try {
                SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                sms.sendTextMessage(numero, null, mensaje, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mensaje enviado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ocurrio un error inesperado, mensaje no enviado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

Comment: El código iba dentro de la publicación @JonaSánchez así que ya te lo agregué

Answer (score 2):

Bien, esta podría ser una respuesta a lo que buscas:

Este sería el xml del layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hola"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/enviar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Get Choice"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lista"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Y esta sería la clase de la activity principal:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lista;
    Button enviar;

    String[] numeros = {
            "1234567890",
            "0987654321",
            "1111111111",
            "2222222222"
            };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
        enviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enviar);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, numeros);
        lista.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

        enviar.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String seleccion = "";
                int cntChoice = lista.getCount();
                SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = lista.getCheckedItemPositions();
                for (int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++) {
                    if (sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                        seleccion += lista.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "\n";
                    }
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), seleccion, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println(seleccion);
            }
        });
    }

    private void enviarMensaje(String numero, String mensaje) {
        try {
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(numero, null, mensaje, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mensaje enviado",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ocurrio un error inesperado, mensaje no enviado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Solo te quedaría implementar el método dentro del botón. Espero te sirva

Comment: Has probado que si "seleccion" almacena los números con salto de linea estos se puedan enviar sin problema?

Comment: Buen punto, yo solo los uní. Editaré la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Para enviar un mensaje recuerda los requerimientos:

• Definir en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` y requerir manualmente el permiso
SEND_SMS

• Tu dispositivo debe tener soporte telefónico ( GSM o CDMA ).

• El teléfono a enviar el mensaje debe escribirse con el código de área.

Puedes ver un ejemplo aquí:

[SMS Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/304160/sms-android-studio)

Si deseas enviar un mensaje de acuerdo a el elemento que seleccionas dentro de un `ListView`, tu `ListView` debe ser configurado como .`CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE`, donde `telefonos` es un array de `Strings` que poblara el listado:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, telefonos);
        lista.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);
```

puedes obtener el valor del teléfono  dentro del `LisView` mediante `.getItemAtPosition()` ejemplo:

```
String telefono =  listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

Crea una lista para almacenar los teléfonos:

```
private List<String> marcaTelefonos = new ArrayList<>();
```

y agrégalos mediante el método `add()` al seleccionarlos:

```
    String telefono =  listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    marcaTelefonos.add(telefono);
```

ahora teniendo la lista de teléfonos envíalos a tu método que realizará el procesamiento de los `SMS`:

```
enviarMensaje(marcaTelefonos , "Buen día mi nombre es Jona Sánchez");
```

Para esto tu método cambiaría ya que recibiría una lista de teléfonos en lugar de solo un teléfono:

```
private void enviarMensaje(List<String> numeros, String mensaje) {
    try {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        for (String numero : numeros){
            //Envia SMSs
            sms.sendTextMessage(numero, null, mensaje, null, null);
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mensaje enviado",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ocurrio un error inesperado, mensaje no enviado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); e.printStackTrace();
    }
```