# Android SMS Received

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

Necesito recibir y enviar SMS desde una APP. Ya he leído todas las propuestas que me otorga stackoverflow cuando coloco el Título, y la verdad el código no difiere mucho o nada en algunos casos de lo que tengo yo.

Según el DEBUG envía el mensaje sms (pero nunca llega al otro celular), pero al intenter recibir no me muestra ningún Log, es como que el BroadcastReceiver nunca se ejecuta.

Características:

Teléfono:  Samsung J7(6) - Android 8.1.0

Permisos: Otorgados (lo verifico con logs)

Ambos dispositivos tienen saldo

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.providers.telephony.SmsProvider" />
```

Parte del Log en donde corroboro

```
    D/MainActivity: PRESIONE BUTTON PARA ENVIAR MENSAJE
    D/MainActivity: SE TIENE PERMISO PARA ENVIAR SMS
    D/MainActivity: BUTTON ENABLED
    D/MainActivity: ESTOY POR MANDAR
    D/MainActivity: MENSAJE ENVIADO
```

Código de envio de mensaje. A modo de prueba lo estoy intentando mandar sin utilizar los editText, les coloco datos a mano.

```
retryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Log.d(TAG, "PRESIONE BUTTON PARA ENVIAR MENSAJE");
                EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_main);
                String destinationAddress = editText.getText().toString();
                EditText smsEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sms_message);
                String smsMessage = smsEditText.getText().toString();
                String scAddress = null;
                PendingIntent sentIntent = null, deliveryIntent = null;
                checkForSmsPermission();
                Log.d(TAG, "ESTOY POR MANDAR");
                try {
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage("1111111111", null, "Envio de Prueba", null, null);
                    //smsManager.sendTextMessage(destinationAddress, scAddress, smsMessage, sentIntent, deliveryIntent);
                    Log.d(TAG, "MENSAJE ENVIADO");
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "MENSAJE NO ENVIADO");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

El número intenté colocarlo con la caracteristica sin cero y con cero, por ejemplo 2940556655 o 02940556655

Mi BroadcastReceiver para recibir los mensajes

String strMessage = "";

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
if (bundle != null)
{
    Object[] sms = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    for (int i=0; i < sms.length; i++)
    {
        SmsMessage mensajes = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) (sms[i]));
        String numero = mensajes.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
        String mensaje = mensajes.getMessageBody().toString();
        strMessage += "SMS from " + numero;
        strMessage += " :" + mensaje;
        Log.d(TAG, "MENSAJE RECIBIDO: " + mensaje);
        Log.d(TAG, "SENDER: : " + numero);
        Toast.makeText(context, strMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Nunca se ejecutan esos Log

Muchas gracias por su ayuda de antemano.

Comment: El número debe definirse con "+", seguido del código de área y el número telefónico, revisa mi respuesta y trata nuevamente.

Answer (score 0):

El código que muestras es correcto, me parece que el problema es como defines el número telefónico, debes definir correctamente el número y mensaje, muy importante definir el código de área.

Por ejemplo, si tu número es 53061212 y tu número de área es 55, debes definir de esta forma el número (+55 53061212), ejemplo:

```
String phone = "+5553061212";
String text = "Hola desde Stackoverflow.com";
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phone, null, text , null, null);
```

---

No olvides los [requisitos para envio de SMS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/304212/95)